# Library with useful prototype functions

Tags: javascript

I was wondering if there is any nice library out there which contains useful functions for Strings, Arrays etc., preferably through prototype.

For myself, I coded the following trivial yet commonly needed functions:

```
String.prototype.contains = function(value) {
 return this.indexOf(value) > -1;
}

String.prototype.amount = function(value) {
 return this.split(value).length - 1;
}
```

However, it gets dirty if I need to have to assemble all such functions each time I come across or need such a function.

So, is there any library with this kind of basic and useful functions for Strings etc.?

Thanks.

Comment: i believe it would be tough to assemble functions as people add them on need basis and then the standard comes along (ECMAScript 5) and addresses some more. Whenever you right such code, its better to check if the standard started providing such a function, so that we use the standard's function than user defined. Once such requirement of mine is to find if an Object[Array Object] is empty in JS.

Comment: As far as I know, the String prototype does not contain these two functions.

Comment: i mean when you develop this code and as time passes, the Browsers will implement standard regulations, so then its better to let the browser execute native JS code than user defined code. my javascript guru 'Doughlas Crockford' can answer it better at http://javascript.crockford.com/remedial.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May you'll find more in the answers of [this SO-question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/472644/javascript-collection-of-one-line-useful-functions)

Answer (score 1):

String Prototype extended found here -> http://stilldesigning.com/dotstring/jquery.string.1.0.js [JQuery specific though]

Comment: Looks extremely useful, but how can I actually access those functions? "test".camelize() e.g. returns an error that the function does not exist.

Comment: Ah, thanks (and I'm sorry, could have figured out that myself...)

Comment: finally some1 said thanks, you really have no clue how it makes me feel today. thanks a lot sire.